# Preventing users from recording playback videos in browser using NextJS

Tags: next.js, browser, video-streaming, drm, screen-recording

I'm currently doing R&D on a project for a client using **NextJS**, and we're facing a requirement where the client needs *to implement a robust solution to prevent users from recording the playback videos within the browser environment*. Essentially, we need to ensure that users cannot perform screen recording regardless of the browser they're using.

I've tried several approaches, including using libraries like recordrtc adn tweaking them, but I haven't been successful in preventing screen recording.I also tried detecting and blocking the screen recording extensions using JS scripts, but wasn't successful in preventing the screen recording.

After researching, I came across articles suggesting that it's not possible to prevent screen recording on browsers that lack hardware DRM support, such as Chrome and Firefox. Is there any workaround or solution available to achieve this in NextJS, or is it currently not possible to prevent screen recording entirely?

Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!